# How to merge 2 loops, such that the value from the object is overlapped?

Tags: javascript, angular, loops

I want to map domainChannels and userChannels such that whenever a channel value in domainChannel is "N", the checkbox is disabled on userChannel.

This is my output right now:
[image]

This is my desired output:

[image]

Here is a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-62bzhs

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Here is a stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-62bzhs

Comment: Based on domainChannel channel property do you want to disable channelValue formcontrol disable?

Comment: Yes.. I have edited question, please check desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since disable state of channelValue form control based on domainChannel property pass domainChannels channels property as a second argument to pushEvent method, so that based on channels object property we can set disable formControl state dynamically.

Change the code as follows in component.

**component.ts**

```
 eventArray(data) {
    let arr = this.controls.eventArray as FormArray;
    arr.controls = [];

    data.map((event,index) => {
      arr.push(this.pushEvent(event,this.domainChannels[index].channels))
    })
  }

 pushEvent(event, domainChannel) {
    const form = this.fb.group({
      eventName: event.eventType,
      transId: event.transId,
      channelArray: this.fb.array([])
    })

    this.pushChannel(form, event.channels,domainChannel)
    return form;
  }
```

To disable form control we can pass disabled key property to formControl object

```
this.fb.group({ channelName: item, channelValue: {value: channels[item] == 'Y' ? true : false,disabled:domainChannel[item] === 'Y' ? false : true}});
```

In html we should not bind value attribute when using reactive form remote that code well.

**component.html**

```
 <tbody formArrayName = "eventArray">
      <tr *ngFor="let event of userPreferenceForm.controls.eventArray.controls;index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td>{{event.get('eventName').value}}</td>
        <ng-container formArrayName = "channelArray">
          <ng-container  *ngFor="let control of event.controls.channelArray.controls;index as j" [formGroupName]="j">
            <td><input type="checkbox" 
              formControlName="channelValue" ></td>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        <td width="10%">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yykrkt?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

Replace

```
channelValue: channels[item] == 'Y' ? true : false,
```

With

```
channelValue: this.domainChannels[index]['channels'][item] == 'Y' ? true : false,
```

Comment: I don't want to change `channelValue` I want to change `isDisabled`, so that the checkbox is disabled whenever it encounters `"N"` in `domainChannels`. please check my stackblitz also